# Creating an instance of a struct within a struct constructor in C++ without dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, struct

I need to create an instance of a struct `Inner` inside a struct `Outer` as in an example below. I can do it with using a pointer, but without it I receive an error "There is no default constructor for `Inner`". Is it possible not to use dynamic allocation in this case?

I looked through many similar questions, but didn't find an example of calling a constructor within an another struct constructor.

```
#include <memory>

struct Inner
{
public:
    Inner(int n)
    {
        a = std::make_unique<double>(n);
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<double> a;
};

struct Outer
{
public:
    Outer(int n)
    {
        in = Inner(n); // Error
        in1 = new Inner(n); // It works
    }
private:
    Inner in;
    Inner* in1;
};
```

Comment: If you use the initializer list syntax your problems go away because you can construct `in` directly in the initializer list instead of default constructing it first and then reassigning it in the constructor body.

Comment: Mmm already closed. The dupe solves your problem, but it's worth mentioning that your `Inner` has no default constructor, because you provided a parametric constructor `Inner(int)`. Then, assuming you have `Outer(int n): in{n}`, this would work `in = Inner(n);`, and would use implicit move constructor. However `in = in2` would not compile, because `Inner` copy constructor is implicitly deleted, because of `unique_ptr` member.

Comment: The distinction between initialization and assignment is very important in C++.